# Flutter run external App after selection?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to include an selection of all apps on the device, that the user can select the app? Also the same with Bluetooth connection. The user can select an Bluetooth device and when the device is accessible the selceted app starts? Give it packages for flutter, which can handle this?

Comment: take a look: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

Comment: Whe i understand it correctly, then deep-linking is only to use for links in browser on android and ios not to choose an app that is installed or for bluetooth devices...?